# Execute button click event on button in UICollectionViewCell

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-2022

I have a collection vew cell which contains a button, I now need to code the button click event to handle the click.  Where would I do that?  I tried the collection view source, the cell code and various other places but nothing works, in fact I can't even get past intellisense. Anyone know how I can do this?

My Cell Code:

```
    public DeptMemberCell(CGRect frame) : base(frame)
    {
        btnRemoveFromDept.SetTitle("Remove From Dept.", UIControlState.Normal);
        btnRemoveFromDept.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 215, 0);
        btnRemoveFromDept.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
        ContentView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
        ContentView.Layer.BorderWidth = 2.0f;
        ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
        ContentView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
        imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("placeholder.png"));
        imageView.Center = ContentView.Center;
        imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
        lblName = new UILabel();
        lblName.Frame = new CGRect(0, ContentView.Bounds.Height - 26, ContentView.Bounds.Width + 25, 26);
        btnRemoveFromDept.Frame = new CGRect(0, ContentView.Bounds.Height, ContentView.Bounds.Width + 25, 26);
        UIView MyContentView = new UIView();
        MyContentView.Add(imageView);
        MyContentView.Add(lblName);
        MyContentView.Add(btnRemoveFromDept);
        MyContentView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, ContentView.Bounds.Width, ContentView.Bounds.Height);
        MyContentView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
        MyContentView.AddConstraints(
           imageView.AtTopOf(MyContentView, 0),
           imageView.AtLeftOf(MyContentView, 0),
           lblName.Below(imageView, 2),
           lblName.AtLeftOf(MyContentView, 0),
           lblName.Width().EqualTo(frame.Width),
           btnRemoveFromDept.Below(lblName, 2),
           btnRemoveFromDept.AtLeftOf(MyContentView, 0)
        );
        ContentView.AddSubview(MyContentView);
    }
```

Everything appears where it should and functions as designed except I cannot seem to figure out where/how to handle the button click event.  I'm using Visual Studio v17.6.2.

Comment: Please show us what you’ve tried and what specific errors you’re getting.  I would expect any event handlers to go into the same class as their UI, just as with any .NET event handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, apparently I didn't try EVERYTHING.  I put the following lines of code in my DeptMemberCell:

```
    this.btnRemoveFromDept.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        int x = 0;
        x++;
    };
```

I put a break on the `x++` and tested the code, worked like a charm.  My code now is as follows:

```
public DeptMemberCell(CGRect frame) : base(frame)
{
    btnRemoveFromDept.SetTitle("Remove From Dept.", UIControlState.Normal);
    btnRemoveFromDept.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromRGB(255, 215, 0);
    btnRemoveFromDept.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Black, UIControlState.Normal);
    ContentView.Layer.BorderColor = UIColor.LightGray.CGColor;
    ContentView.Layer.BorderWidth = 2.0f;
    ContentView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
    ContentView.Transform = CGAffineTransform.MakeScale(1.0f, 1.0f);
    imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("placeholder.png"));
    imageView.Center = ContentView.Center;
    imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;
    lblName = new UILabel();
    lblName.Frame = new CGRect(0, ContentView.Bounds.Height - 26, ContentView.Bounds.Width + 25, 26);
    btnRemoveFromDept.Frame = new CGRect(0, ContentView.Bounds.Height, ContentView.Bounds.Width + 25, 26);
    UIView MyContentView = new UIView();
    MyContentView.Add(imageView);
    MyContentView.Add(lblName);
    MyContentView.Add(btnRemoveFromDept);
    MyContentView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, ContentView.Bounds.Width, ContentView.Bounds.Height);
    MyContentView.SubviewsDoNotTranslateAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints();
    MyContentView.AddConstraints(
       imageView.AtTopOf(MyContentView, 0),
       imageView.AtLeftOf(MyContentView, 0),
       lblName.Below(imageView, 2),
       lblName.AtLeftOf(MyContentView, 0),
       lblName.Width().EqualTo(frame.Width),
       btnRemoveFromDept.Below(lblName, 2),
       btnRemoveFromDept.AtLeftOf(MyContentView, 0)
    );
    ContentView.AddSubview(MyContentView);
    this.btnRemoveFromDept.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
    {
        int x = 0;
        x++;
    };
}
```